# editing image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just playing with javascript and HTML but I can't solve one error.
I've created a button and added eventLister on it then I created a simple function which should set up the background image, but instead it's undefined

```
document.getElementById("failure").addEventListener("click" ,dang);
function dang(){
    let info =  prompt("Enter link to new IMG");
        document.querySelector(".upperDivImage").style.backgroundImage = `url(${info})`;
        console.log("gut")
}
```

Comment: so what i should do then

Comment: Function declarations are [hoisted](http://adripofjavasc'tript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html) so `dang` is defined here. What exactly is "undefined?" What's the exact error you're getting? Posting your HTML (in your question) might be useful as well, as well as the url you've used that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: actualy no error in console but that div where i was setting up background image, shows with background-image:url(undefined)

Comment: Presuming everything else is okay, you should try wrapping the image url in quotes. I.e: `url("${info}")`

Answer (score 1):

This actually works. Here is a working example (of your code). 
Notice that if you use a div you need to give it width and height for it to display

```js
document.getElementById("failure").addEventListener("click", dang);

function dang() {
  let info = prompt("Enter link to new IMG");
  document.querySelector(".upperDivImage").style.backgroundImage = `url(${info})`;
  console.log("gut")
}
```

```css
.upperDivImage {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="failure">click me</div>
<div class="upperDivImage" />
```